# Before CheckIn-Event for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file on sharepoint which is to be checked out to make changes on it.
These new changes should be exported to an access file, which is not part of the problem.
The problem is that the code for the export to an access table should start right before one checks in the document to the server.

Does anyone have an idea how to execute this? I could not find a before check in event like the before save event.

Thanks!

Comment: Excel VBA has no notion of CheckIn. There is no such event handler. The problem seems to be more of a SharePoint problem than an Excel VBA problem. Perhaps this will help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/44b66105-25ef-43de-8da1-f624b4b00781/using-excel-with-vba-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for your response. Why do you think it is a SharePoint problem? I don't want to use Excel VBA over/in SharePoint, I just want to run VBA code in Excel while the file is being checked in.
Btw I found out by trying out using BeforeSafe event for my problem that it runs my code in this event when I check in the file!

Comment: I was just guessing. I don't know SharePoint, but "being checked in" is not an Excel notion at all. It does seem to be a SharePoint notion. Thus, your question involves something from SharePoint that has no direct link to the Excel Object Model. If you solved your question, perhaps you could post it as an answer. Others might have the same question.